# Unable to set the image from Gallery in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

Recently, I'm making a simple app, and I've been stuck for a while with a minor problem that I've read about over the web.

I'm trying to set the image from the gallery in android to the imageView in a fragment, however, whenever I select the image the app shuts down. I've read about the similar problems within  this site but the solution doesn't solve my problem. Perhaps, without knowing, I might been setting up the things differently, but I cannot see the problem to the code,I've set a sample code below.

```
 ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Button01))
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                        }
                    });


            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (data != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
//I want to set the image in this imageView     
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                cursor.close();
            } else {

            }
```

Comment: If your app shuts down then you can see the reason in the logcat. So post the relevant pieces of the logcat please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Use this permission in your manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

//Use this code for intent...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),REQUEST_GET_PHOTO);
```

//onResultActivity:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            System.out.println("Get the Image from data");

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
        }
```